# How to get CSS for a rounder corner with header included

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image: This is a picture representation. Exactly I want to know the css rules needed to achieve this]

This is a picture representation. Exactly I want to know the css rules needed to achieve this

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/NUMcr/1/ It's just an example

Comment: Thanks Roman... Thumbs Up...

Answer (score 1):

That's the fieldset of a form.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Title:</legend>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Access Group:</legend>
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border-radius: 3px;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Appreciate the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using html `fieldset` and `legend` tag. To get the rounded corners just use `border-radius` property.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Have a look at that fiddle: **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUMcr/335/)**